# How can I set the query string for a request within a unit test in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am writing unit tests for my ASP.NET Core site, and I need to be able to set the query string for the request. How can I set the query string for a request within a unit test in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You first must first build the object tree of `Controller` -> `ControllerContext` -> `DefaultHttpContext`. The request property for a `DefaultHttpContext` object has the type `DefaultHttpRequest`. So, if you cast `HttpContext.Request` to `DefaultHttpRequest` you are able to set the QueryString parameter.

```
var controller = new FunController()
{
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
    {
        HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
    }
};
controller.HttpContext.Request as DefaultHttpRequest).QueryString = new QueryString("?funfactor=100");
```

Comment: Under different circumstances, I should be using query string parameter binding to avoid the complexity of mocking the query string.

Comment: Anyone on .net 6 (or above) reading this, `DefaultHttpRequest` [was made internal after](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/377) .net core 3.0.
For me, I was able to get my unit tests working with `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` `var httpRequest = new DefaultHttpContext().Request;` `httpRequest.QueryString = new QueryString($"?from={myFromValue:s}&to={myToValue:s}");` `var handler = new MyController();` `var result = await handler.MyMethod(httpRequest);`

Answer (score 6):

In case you are OK to use `Integration testing` you could also use `TestServer` approach. See the details here - [Testing controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing). In this case the test for controller action with query parameters might look like this:

```
var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseEnvironment("Testing")
    .UseStartup<Startup>();

var server = new TestServer(hostBuilder);
var client = server.CreateClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/mycontroller/things?param=value").Result;
```

Comment: Good point. I haven't dug into integration testing for ASP.NET Core, but it does look promising.

Comment: From my point of view, integration testing is much more convenient for testing controllers (and infrastructure in general). Unit tests are more suitable for testing all kinds of repositories, services and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to override the Query I used the `QueryString` field like the following

```
var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
context.Request.QueryString = new QueryString("?key=value");
```

Credit to [Simon C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389018/simon-c) on the first comment

Answer (score 1):

I used controller context to create HttpContext in Asp.net Core 7.0

```
        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContextMock
            .SetupGet(x => x.Request.QueryString)
            .Returns(() =>
            {
                return QueryString.Create("param1", "param1Val");
            });
        _controler.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object;
        // Act 
        var result = await _controler.MyCallAsync();
```